# How to solve Uncaught datepicker error in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am getting this error continuosly due to to datepicker (jQuery)

```
jquery-ui.js:7884 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
    at _showDatepicker (jquery-ui.js:7884)
    at e (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (VM124 jquery.min.js:2)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (VM124 jquery.min.js:4)
```

Following is the order of the `<script>` and `<link>` tags I have put down inside `<head>` tag in handlebar page.

```
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/fontfamily.css' />

  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@2.1.7/dist/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> -->

</head>
```

I think the problem is arising due to using the 2 versions of the same link or some tags should be put above or below. I tried to do that but still getting the same error.
I want the exact order of the tags or the links i should remove.
Please help!!!

UPDATE:

Error code in console:

```
_showDatepicker: function( input ) {
        input = input.target || input;
        if ( input.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "input" ) { // find from button/image trigger
            input = $( "input", input.parentNode )[ 0 ];
        }
```

Comment: some code refers to `xxx.target` ... and `xxx` is undefined - but you've shown no code - it also looks like you're NOT loading `bootstrap-datepicker`

Comment: `jQuery UI 1.12 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer.` I think it doesn't support jquery 3.x.x. try moving to jquery 1.x.x or jquery 2.x.x.

Comment: @Bravo I dont have that code inside anywhere written where the code is occuring. its the error in .ui.js file itslef which I hve just imported it.